# Store 3d array from Java in .mat file

Tags: java, arrays, matlab

Im trying to store a 3 dimensional array made in Java in Matlab but some mistake on my part is resulting in repeated data being stored i.e. data of 1st dimension is replicated in other dimensions too.

Im using the JMatIO library for this purpose

Java Code

```
int[] dims = {Xtimeseries.length,Xtimeseries[0].length,Xtimeseries[0][0].length};
MLDouble Xtimeseriesmat = new MLDouble("Xtimeseries", dims);
for(int i = 0 ; i < dims[0]; i++)
    for(int j = 0 ; j < dims[1] ; j++)
        for(int k = 0 ; k < dims[2] ; k++){
            Xtimeseriesmat.set(Xtimeseries[i][j][k],i,j + k*dims[1]);
        }
```

Here Xtimeseries is double[][][]

However when I load this matrix in Matlab im getting the following

```
 Xtimeseries(1,1,1:3)

ans(:,:,1) =

   3.9308e+03


ans(:,:,2) =

   4.1297e+03


ans(:,:,3) =

   3.9985e+03

 Xtimeseries(2,1,1:3)

ans(:,:,1) =

   3.9308e+03


ans(:,:,2) =

   4.1297e+03


ans(:,:,3) =

   3.9985e+03
```

What error am I making while storing the array in MLDouble?

Comment: You are recurring over dims[][][] fine. No worries about that. Problem must be in that MLDouble, probably you are not using well that set method. If that MLDouble is http://intra.csb.ethz.ch/javadoc/metabolic/com/jmatio/types/MLDouble.html in fact it looks like MLDouble can only hold 2D arrays... Hard to give an answer without more details on MLDouble.

Comment: Yes I am using this MLDouble data type only as mentioned on the link you have mentioned